# How to make a linked list from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's the basic code

```js
function ListNode(x) {
  this.value = x;
  this.next = null;
}

function linkedList(arr){
  let list = new ListNode(arr[0]);
  
  let selectedNode = list;
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    selectedNode.next = new ListNode(arr[i]);
    selectedNode = selectedNode.next
  } 

  return list
}

l = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(linkedList(l));
```

For some reason, it just works. I don't get how the '**list**' variable is changing/updating in **linkedList(arr)** function. I see selectedNode = list, but **list** never changes. **list** initializes with the constructor new **ListNode(arr[0])** but after that, the only variable that's changing is **selectedNode**. There isn't even code for **list.next** to change to something.

So how is it that return list returns the full linked list?

Comment: The list variable points to the head of the list. Then it sets selectednode to point to the head also. By setting select nodes next to point to a new node, it is changing the same top node that list is pointing to. The. Selectnode moved to that new next node and it keeps linking more and more nodes. All the while list is still pointing to that first node.

Comment: `selectedNode === list === new ListNode(arr[0])`

Comment: It's just how `LinkedList` works, concept-wise. You only need to have a pointer to the **head** node. The *list* results by setting new nodes to the `next` pointer of nodes. So in the end you have a chain where your `head` points with `head.next` to another node and this node again points to some node with its `next` variable and so on. You can also clearly see this in the output, it's a *nested structure*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do this `let selectedNode = list;` two variables are pointing to the same value in memory, in this case, `list` and `selectedNode`.  So, the chain of modifications starts with list and downstream adding new linked nodes.

The author has initialized the `selectedNode` with `list` as a starting point (root node) of the linked list.

**This how looks like the memory with this `let selectedNode = list;`**

```
  +-----------------+------------------+
  |       list      |  selectedNode    |
  +-----------------+------------------+
  |                 |         |        |
  |   {value: 3,    |         |        |
  |    next: null } <---------+        |
  |                 |                  |    
  +-----------------+------------------+
```

So, every iteration will modify the same `list` object because the next node is bound/linked with the previous nodes:

```
selectedNode.next = new ListNode(arr[i]);  i = 1
+-------------------+------------------+
|       list        |  selectedNode    |
+-------------------+------------------+
|                   |            |     |
|   {               |            |     |
|     value: 3,     | Points to  |     |
|     next: {       | next       |     |
|        value: 1   <------------+     |
|        next: null |                  |
|      }            |                  |
|   }               |                  |
|                   |                  |    
+-------------------+------------------+

selectedNode.next = new ListNode(arr[i]);  i = 2
+-----------------------+------------------+
|       list            |  selectedNode    |
+-----------------------+------------------+
|                       |            |     |
|   {                   |            |     |
|     value: 3,         |            |     |
|     next: {           |            |     |
|        value: 1       | Points to  |     |
|        next: {        | next       |     |
|           value: 2,   <------------+     |
|           next: null  |                  |
|         }             |                  |
|     }                 |                  |
|   }                   |                  |
|                       |                  |    
+-----------------------+------------------+
```

And so on.

Comment: I think I see. So by adding new to list, you make it a constructor instead of a variable containing a value. Still trying to figure out how returning list returns all the other variables, but I'll keep re-reading until I understand

Comment: It returns the whole thing because when you `selectedNode = selectedNode.next`, it is also still the same in memory. In the next iteration, when you change the new `selectedNode`, you're actually changing the old `selectedNode`'s `next` key, which is actually changing `list`.

Comment: lol thanks Oliver. This is so confusing. I've never seen javascript share variables like this. Edit: Is there a tutorial/similar SO question I can read to elaborate on this?

Comment: @TylerL hold on, I think with a graphic you will understand.

Comment: @TylerL take a look at the updated answer.  Let me know if you understand.

Comment: Ah! That's super helpful! Thank you for helping me understand this.

Answer (score 18):

```js
function linkedList(arr){
  return arr.reduceRight((next, value) => ({value, next}), null);
}

l = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(linkedList(l));
```

you don't need the class `ListNode` for such a simple object.

Comment: Please give explanation...

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an object type to a variable, the variable's value isn't the actual object but rather a reference to it. Therefore, when you do `selectedNode = list` both variables reference the same object and any changes to this object, using any of the references to it, will be visible from any of its references.
In short: the `list` variable doesn't change but the object it's referencing does.

Comment: So in the loop, when selectedNode.next changes, it's really changing list! What about having multiple linked lists using the same constructor function? Not possible?

Comment: @TylerL Oh, it's definitely possible. If by constructor function you're talking about the `linkedList(arr) {}` function (which is more of a factory function), every call to it creates a new linked list since the `list` variable is local to the function and every function call has its own instance.